# How do I set the url to make an ajax request for a html document?

Tags: ajax

I have a javacript file that uses ajax to load an html document, but WordPress changes the url.  Is there a way to set the url so that WordPress doesn’t change it?

```
var file =  ‘test/file.html’;
```

WordPress appends the file to `/wp-admin/` and sets the path to 
`http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/test/file.html`

When I change the file path to `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/plugings/test/file.html`, WordPress still uses the ajaxurl global variables and sets the path to the `wp-admin` directory. Here's the code:

```
return $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'html',
    url: file,   
    success: function (resp) {
        alert(‘Success’);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        alert('Error ‘);
    }
});
```

Comment: WordPress won't interfere with your front end scripts like that. Can you please include the full context of where you're setting the URL in the script, relative to the rest of the script that you've included. Keep in mind that `‘test/file.html’;` is a relative URL, and will be appended to whatever the current URL is. You should include the full URL to the file to avoid this.

Comment: Whether I used a relative path or url it didn't matter.  WordPress appends both to the $ajaxurl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is such way: you should pass absolute path in there...

Let's say your JS file is enqueued like this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script', 'path-to-js-file.js'... );
```

Then you should use `wp_localize_script` and pass the value in there:

```
wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'MyScriptData', array( 'ajax_url' => site_url('/test/file.html') ) );
```

Then you can access this value in your JS file this way:

```
return $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'html',
    url: MyScriptData.ajax_url, // <-- here you get that value...
    success: function (resp) {
        alert(‘Success’);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR) {
        alert('Error ‘);
    }
});
```

### BUT...

**You should know, that you SHOULD process AJAX requests using proper actions and not with some external file. Here you can read more about dealing with AJAX in WordPress: [AJAX in Plugins](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)**